# SSRS Subscription for Previous Month

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, default, subscription

I have SSRS report that has a month parameter. When the report runs the month parameter should default to current month (the user wants to see current month data when running from report manager)

I want to schedule this report to be delivered via email so it runs at the beginning of every month but should select previous month (meaning ignoring the default month parameter of current month).

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a data driven subscription. Use the below query to get the start date and end date. (Add other parameter columns that you might need to the query).

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) as [Start Date], DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) as [End Date]
```

Hope it helps. Please mark it as an answer, if it is.